# Getting 'Unable to find valid certification path to requested target' in Glassfish but not in standalone Java App

Tags: java, certificate, glassfish

Working with Eclipse IDE, given the following class, from which I omit everything unnecessary:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
//...

@WebServiceClient
public class CustomService extends Service {
    
    public CustomService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    //...   
}
```

When it is invoked from the 'main' method of another **standalone class**, when passing through the line **super(wsdlLocation, serviceName)**, it works correctly.

BUT, when it is invoked from a class that is executed upon **Glassfish** loading, when passing through the line **super(wsdlLocation, serviceName)**, it throws the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works in my case:

From **EDGE** explorer, I had to access the WSDL URL and **export the certificate**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Move it to the **config** path of **Glassfish** (C:\PROYECT\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config), and from there, import it.

**`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias DigiCert_Global_Root_G2 -file "DigiCert Global Root G2.crt" -keystore cacerts.jks`**